# Parsing error in react with style-components

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a light/dark mode switch in React with this tutorial - [Tutorial Link](https://css-tricks.com/a-dark-mode-toggle-with-react-and-themeprovider/)

After adding GlobalStyles from styled-components even that I was doing all according to tutorial I receive this error:

```
./src/Components/Global.js
  Line 13:40:  Parsing error: Unterminated template

  11 |     align-items: center;
  12 |     background: ${({ theme }) => theme.body};
> 13 |     color: ${({ theme }) => theme.text};
     |                                        ^
  14 |     display: flex;
  15 |     flex-direction: column;
  16 |     justify-content: center;
```

Here is code from Global.js

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';

export const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`
  *,
  *::after,
  *::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    align-items: center;
    background: ${({ theme }) => theme.body};
    color: ${({ theme }) => theme.text};
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: BlinkMacSystemFont, -apple-system, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    transition: all 0.25s linear;
  }
```

And here is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { GlobalStyles } from './Components/Global';
import { ThemeProvider} from 'styled-components';
import { lightTheme, darkTheme} from './Components/Theme'

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={lightTheme}>
    <>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <button>Toggle theme</button>
      <h1>It's a light theme!</h1>
      <footer>
      </footer>
    </>
  </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Question: How I can fix that error and did I miss something in syntax which leads to this error?

Comment: Are you terminating `GlobalStyles` string with a closing backtick? Can't see one in your code

Comment: @Jayce444 Yes it is. export const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`

Comment: @Jayce444 Alright, the problem solved It was a missing backtick in last string. my bad

Comment: Well it seems, you are missing a backtick.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Yes, already saw it as well. Thanks!